# \label: escape or remove LaTeX commands

Tags: beamer, macros, labels, parameters

The CI of my company requires a section separation Page with a custom layout.
Part of this is a color box containig the section number on the upper right corner while the section title is aligned *left center*.

I created my own command:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

%% does not reflect the target layout, just the principle
\newcommand{\beamersection}[1]{\section{#1}\label{#1}
  \begin{frame}{} 
    \colorbox{gray}{\Huge\ref{#1}}\hspace{2em}\huge\nameref{#1}
  \end{frame}}

\begin{document}
   \beamersection{a \textit{styled} section} %% gives error
\end{document}
```

the problem with this is, since the section title is used as unique label I get compilation errors, wen the section title contains LaTeX commands.

Is there a way to escape backslashes and curly braces or remove the LaTeX commands while passing them to `\label`?
Or is there another way of createing a unique label within `\newcommand`?

Just for the records:
the error thrown is:
`! Argument of \@gobble has an extra }.<inserted text>\par \beamersection{UnitTest \textit{in} Java}`

Comment: There surely are better ways. Perhaps, instead of showing only what you have, explain what you're after. Of course `\nameref` will complain when you pass it formatting commands like `\textit`. Moreover, why would you set a `\label` with all the formatting commands. I'd suggest an alternative interface.

Comment: I _did_ explain what I need: the section number in a color box and the vertically centered, left aligned name of the section. And what I postesd does what I want except when I want to "style" the section name.

Comment: Have a look at the beamer manual, paying attention to `\AtBeginSection`

Comment: Using the section title as an automatic label is a very bad idea, just my personal opinion.

Comment: why do `\label{#1}`  rather than `\label{#2}` and have a second argument for the label? having the section title as a label is strange, having formatting like `\textit` in `\label` is just wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: _"why do \label{#1} rather than \label{#2} and have a second argument for the label?"_ becaus it makes the use harder. section names are unique, so what is the point in adding another unique id from the users view? IMHO the usage of the solution must be as indipendent from its technical implementation as possible.

Comment: @samcarter: _"Using the section title as an automatic label is a very bad idea"_ I agree, but its the best I came up with. What is yours?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle but if you mangle the section title to make it legal as a `label` then either the user will need to know exactly how it was made safe or you will have to redefine `\ref` to do the same, otherwise how will anyone refer to this label? the whole point of `\label` is a small unique identifier that is stable even if the document is edited so titles and numbers change

Comment: @DavidCarlisle _"how will anyone refer to this label?"_ nobody needs to, this lable is only used within the completly auto generated section separation frame (remember, it's a beamer presentation). If someone needs a reference to the section she is expected to create a new label...

Comment: well why does it need a label at all in that case?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: _"well why does it need a label at all in that case? "_ because it was the best idea **I** had. would be glad to see a better solution...

Comment: the `\label` isn't needed you could use `#1` instead of `\nameref{#1]` but you get the same error anyway as beamer tries to write the pdf bookmark from the section heading, \texorpdfstring as in the posted answer addresses that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your expected output is, but from your code I image something like this:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{section page}{bg=gray}
\setbeamerfont{section title}{size=\huge}
\setbeamerfont{section name}{size=\Huge}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}{%
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \hfill%
        \colorbox{section page.bg}{%
            \usebeamerfont{section name}%
            \sectionname~\insertsectionnumber%
        }\par
        \vfill
        \usebeamerfont{section title}
        \insertsection\par
        \vfill
    \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSection{\sectionpage}

\begin{document}   
   \section{a \texorpdfstring{\itshape styled\upshape}{styled} section}
   \frame{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the right direction bit still ugly to use...

Comment: Using style commands in arguments is ugly, not this :)

Comment: `\texorpdfstring{\itshape styled\upshape}{styled}` has duplicated text, so I'd like to change it  to `\textit{styled}`, but then I get the same compile error as with my original solution.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle `\protect` helps: `\protect\textit{styled}`

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter

\newif\ifobeystylecommands\obeystylecommandsfalse
%%
\newcommand\disobeystylecommands{%
  \ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {}%
  {\texorpdfstring{\obeystylecommandsfalse}{}}%
}%
%%    
\newcommand\obeystylecommands{}%
\let\obeystylecommands=\disobeystylecommands
%%    
\newcommand\savedobeystylecommands{%
  \ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {}%
  {\texorpdfstring{\obeystylecommandstrue}{}}%
}%
%%
\newcommand\CallStyleCommand[1]{%
  \ifobeystylecommands
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\texorpdfstring{#1}{\@firstofone}}%
  {\@firstofone}%
}%
%%
\newcommand\StyledNameref[1]{%
  {%
    \let\obeystylecommands=\savedobeystylecommands
    \disobeystylecommands
    \nameref{#1}%
  }%
}%
%%
%% does not reflect the target layout, just the principle
\newcommand{\beamersection}[1]{%
  \section{{\obeystylecommands#1}}%
  {\disobeystylecommands\label{#1}}%
  \begin{frame}{}%
    \colorbox{gray}{%
      \Huge{\disobeystylecommands\ref{#1}}%
    }%
    \hspace{2em}%
    \huge
    \StyledNameref{#1}%
  \end{frame}%
}%

\makeatother    

\begin{document}

\beamersection{a \CallStyleCommand{\textit}{styled} section}

\beamersection{another \CallStyleCommand{\textbf}{styled} section}

\beamersection{yet another \CallStyleCommand{\textit}{\CallStyleCommand{\footnotesize}{styled}} section}

\beamersection{one more \CallStyleCommand{\textbf}{\CallStyleCommand{\textcolor{green}}{styled}} section}

\nameref{a styled section}

\nameref{another styled section}

\nameref{yet another styled section}

\nameref{one more styled section}

\StyledNameref{a styled section}

\StyledNameref{another styled section}

\StyledNameref{yet another styled section}

\StyledNameref{one more styled section}

\ref{a styled section}

\ref{another styled section}

\ref{yet another styled section}

\ref{one more styled section}

\end{document}
```